# Ubuntu-tweek installation error

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I've ubuntu-tweak 0.8.7-1trusty2 trying installing on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Error is:
Dependency is not satisfiable : gksu
How to solve it?

Comment: Try installing .deb with Gdebi or software center. They check for dependencies.

Comment: @Sudheer I'm trying from ubuntu software center with deb package there prompts error

Comment: @user73898 You have to satisfy dependency by updating from repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing form terminal(`ctrl+Alt+T`):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: For try that where I need to put ubuntu tweak.deb or it will install by repository

Comment: @user73898 will be automatically installed from repositories.

Comment: No .deb is not needed it will download ubuntu-tweak and its dependencies form net. You should be connected to internet.

Comment: Gdebi & software center are also working fine with .deb packages. I just tried them. You need to have network connection to download dependencies.